# Define dummies before and after an event

Tags: r, time, dummy-variable, economics

I have an event which happened at t=0. I'd like to create dummies for t-10, t-9,..., t-2, t-1, t=0, t+1, t+2 ... t+10.

I have the following data structure:

```
Date     t=0    t-10     t-9 ... t+10
2015-1     0       0       0       0  
2015-2     0       0       0       0
2015-3     0       0       0       0
2015-4     1       0       0       0
 ...       0       0       0       0 
2017-12    0       0       0       0
```

I want to create the value 1 in the column "t-10" when the event happened 10 months before t=0 equals 1 (event happened) and so on until t+10.

Comment: Your natural language description is unclear. What would be the "correct" answer for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.  It's not elegant, but it gets the job done:

```
# generate sample date data to work with
df <- data.frame(
    date = seq(from=as.Date("2015-01-01"), to=as.Date("2015-02-28"), by="day"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# identify the event of interest
event <- as.Date("2015-01-20")

# create a counter for days before/after event
diff <- df$date - event
df$diff <- ifelse(abs(diff) > 10, -999, paste0("t0", diff))

# turn counter into a set of dummy variables
df <- cbind(df, model.matrix( ~ factor(df$diff)))

# clean up by dropping intercept, and reordering and renaming dummies
df$`(Intercept)` <- NULL
df <- df[ , c(1:2, 4, 12:5, 3, 13:14, 16:23, 15)]
names(df)[3:23] <- c( paste0("tm", 10:1), "te0", paste0("tp",1:10))
```

I don't like `-` and `+` signs in variable names so I have named t-8 to be `tm8` and t+3 to be `tp3`.